# SQL select all rows on two joined tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the data of

```
Id  Amt
1   10
2   10

Tbl2
Id Amt
1  10
```

I want a query that will result to this

```
Id Amt
1  20
2  10
```

I tried different joins but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Please always tag the database in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do this is with UNION ALL:

```
    SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) AS AMT FROM (
     SELECT ID, AMT FROM TABLE1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ID, AMT FROM TABLE2
   ) GROUP BY ID;
```

By the way you can do also with a FULL OUTER JOIN being careful to group by ID:

```
SELECT 
    NVL(T1.ID, T2.ID) AS ID, 
    NVL(T1.AMT, 0) + NVL(T2.AMT, 0) AS AMT  
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) AS AMT FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT ID, SUM(AMT) AS AMT FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY ID) T2
ON (T1.ID = T2.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`:

```
select tbl1.id, tbl1.amt + coalesce(tbl2.amt, 0)
from tbl1 left join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Comment: Left Join is used to join N tables together..

For Example:

`SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
      ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id
LEFT JOIN table3
      ON table1.primaryKey=table3.table1Id`

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro but the other row didnt show up :(

Comment: @Mauricio Kenny - What do you mean by “Left join is used to join N tables together”. You mean to say one cannot use left join on just 2 tables ?

Comment: No, I mean 2 or more tables.

Comment: @d_angelosanchez you should use in this case full outer join.